# Optimizar varias consultas anidadas

Tags: sql-server, subconsultas, tsql

Tengo tres niveles de subconsultas:

```
------ Final 26 = Transferencia
select u.LOGIN Agente from DB.dbo.vwTransaccionesTotal ht  left join NDB.dbo.USUARIO U  on ht.idAgente=U.IDUSUARIO
WHERE ht.idAgente = u.IDUSUARIO AND ht.idTransaccion in
(
select idTransaccionOriginal from DB.dbo.vwTransaccionesTotal ht  
WHERE idFinal = 26 AND ht.idTransaccion in
(
select idTransaccionOriginal from DB.dbo.vwTransaccionesTotal T2
    inner join [dbo].SRT_IVR_HIST E on T2.idTransaccion =E.IdTransaccion
)
)
```

relación de tablas-vistas: SRT_IVR_HIST -- vwTransaccionesTotal -- USUARIO

Alguna forma de optimizarlo con CTE?

Comment: Puedo estar equivocado, pero esa consulta tiene muy poco sentido

Comment: idTransaccion identifica una "operación" y idTransaccionOriginal  la operación origen. Es cómo ir atrás en dos pasos para recuperar el valor de "Agente", de la transacción origen (operación) de todas.

Comment: Por supuesto que si!!! que intentaste???

Comment: Cuando hablas de optimizar, supongo que hablas de optimizar el tiempo de ejecución. Para entender el problema de desempeño que estás teniendo habría que ver información sobre la cantidad de registros en cada tabla y el plan de ejecución que el motor está produciendo para la consulta. Por otro lado, si no tienes problemas de desempeño, diría que el esfuerzo de _optimizar prematuramente_ no vale la pena...

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código de la vista vwTransaccionesTotal? ¿Cuál es la estructura de las tablas que la conforman?